# Representation of catboost model in a human-interpretable manner

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, catboost

Among the most popular packages used in modelling problems, there are plenty functions which allow converting the model object into something that can be understood by humans, e.g. xgb.model.dt.tree in xgboost or pretty.gbm.tree in GBM. Is there any similar function in the catboost package or any other possibility to represent a model as, for instance, data frame? 
An object of catboost.Model class is a list with external pointer and raw data elements and the only way to find some info about the structure of model is to save it as a .py file but it's rather a harsh way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `tree_idx` attribute, but it can be used only for tree visualization with [`plot_tree`](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_plot_tree.html), and not directly with `model`; here's a reproducible example with the Boston data:

```
import numpy as np
import catboost
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()
y = boston['target']
X = boston['data']

model = CatBoostRegressor(depth=2, verbose=False, iterations=5).fit(X, y)

model.plot_tree(tree_idx=0)
```

[image]

```
model.plot_tree(tree_idx=4)
```

[image]

Comment: what does the val in leaves mean?

Comment: @NaumanNaeem this is a regression tree, so the values shown are the mean values of the samples that ended up in the respective terminal nodes (leaves).

Comment: Similar values appear when I use catboost classifier, [binary](https://imgur.com/pB80Dtr) as well as [multiclass](https://imgur.com/rrXL0Hc), I'm not sure to what to make of these values. The official tutorial notebook on visualization doesn't mention anything about these.

Comment: @NaumanNaeem comments is not the right space to discuss such things. If you are facing issues, you are very welcome to open  a question.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually posted a question that no one answered. Maybe you want to take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407613/catboos-plot-tree-understanding).