# visualizing Catboost tree - graphviz

Tags: graphviz, catboost

I'm trying to visualize the result of by CatBoostClassifier in Databricks.
I have graphviz ==0.18.2 installed on my cluster.

When I use the following code (NB. model is my trained CatBoostClassifier):

`model.plot_tree(tree_idx=0)`

I don't get a tree, but I get the following output:  <graphviz.graphs.Digraph at 0x7f86330d9640>.

This doesn't seem to happen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197070/representation-of-catboost-model-in-a-human-interpretable-manner) post.

Any suggestions on how I can visualize my tree?

Comment: "graphviz ==0.18.2" is non-standard version.  Please report output from "dot -V"

Comment: It is the latest version of Graphiz, as reporter here: https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/  . How do I get dot-v output,

Comment: At a command line prompt (Linux shell or Windows cmd/powershell) type "dot -V"

Comment: I believe you only installed an interface to Graphviz, but not the actual Graphviz package itself.  This seems to be a common problem, the pypi documentation seems flawed.  Search stackoverflow for "graphviz python"

Comment: Thanks, that might actually be the case. I figured graphiz was a working library, but that might not be the case. I need this to work on Databricks so Powershell is unfortunately not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem in Databricks. The following code works for me. It uses **graphviz** package

```
graph = model.plot_tree(tree_idx=0)
displayHTML(graph.pipe(format="svg").decode("utf-8"))
```